# How to understand which class uses composition?

Tags: c#, .net, oop, composition

I don't understand the difference between these cases of "composition" in c#, could anyone explain?

```
class B
{
}
```

example 1:

```
class A : IDisposable
{
    private B objB;
    public A(){objB = new B();}
    public void Dispose(){}
}
```

example 2:

```
class A : IDisposable
{
    private B objB;
    public A(B obj){this.objB = obj;}
    public void Dispose(){}
}
```

example 3:

```
class A : IDisposable
{
     private B objB;
     public A(){}
     public void Sample(){objB = new B();}
     public void Dispose(){}
}
```

I know that one is not the composition, but I don't understand why.
Also, is there a difference in cases:

```
class B : IDisposable
{
     //is there a difference if I will and won't implement the methods of the interface?
}

class A : IDisposable
{
    public B objB {get;set;}
    public A(){}
    public void Sample(){}
    public void Dispose(){}
}
```

So my questions about composition: 1) Is there a difference if the B in A is private or public? 2) Do I have to initialize the B in A to count it as a composition? If so, is there any difference in what way I will do this? 3) Can I use composition if both my classes implement the same interface, but one of them doesn't implement its methods? (the last example).
Thanks for the answers!

Comment: What do you mean by composition in the first place? What is *not*? In all the cases `A` is composed by `B` and possibly other fields and properties. This sounds like a CS101 question where the only answer is `whatever the prof says it is`. In real software development there's no difference

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_composition#Aggregation.  Though the link is for aggregation, the difference between it and _composition_ is explained.

Comment: Perhaps this will help: https://medium.com/swlh/aggregation-vs-composition-in-object-oriented-programming-3fa4fd471a9f

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos it actually is, it is part of the test from prof. I already finished, but I don't understand the answer, so I decided to ask about it here

Comment: If the question means composition vs aggregation, all examples could be either, depending on whether `A` is meant to own `B`, whether `Dispose` kills B and whether `A` gives `B` to other classes.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I just told you, that the test is finished, but nvm, thx for the link

Comment: What do you compare composition against? Aggregation? Inheritance? We can't help without knowing what the prof's definition is. In general OOP terms it's composition vs aggregation, or composition vs inheritance.

Comment: In fact, in 1 and 3 A owns B assuming there's no other code. If the GC runs, only A has holds any instances of B so if A is an orphan so is B.

Comment: On the other hand, 1 and 2 store the reference to B in the constructor while 3 does this in a method. That doesn't imply anything about ownership but perhaps that's what the prof meant. In a class that uses lazy initialization owned fields may be initialized *after* construction. They're still owned though

Answer (score 0):

All are examples of composition, at least in the sense of composition vs inheritance. A useful memonic is that composition **has a** and inheritance **is a**. I.e. *A **has a** B*. On the other hand *A **is a** IDisposable*.

There is also composition vs aggregation. In this sense composition **owns a** while aggregation **uses a**. Example 1 and 3 are clear examples of ownership. For example 2 it is unclear, in some cases a constructor parameter might imply taking ownership of the object, in other cases it might not, and in some cases there is a separate parameter to decide if ownership should be transferred or not. In any case, "Ownership" usually only matters if the the object is `IDisposable`, so in this trivial example it is not really useful to talk aggregation vs composition.

The examples rather show different way to take dependencies, if the object B is required for the correct functioning of the object A, then A *depends on* B.

- Example 1 is simply creating its dependency, and is typical when depending on 'simple' objects, like a list.
- Example 2 can be called *dependency injection*, and is usually a good idea for more complex object hierarchies.
- Example 3 could be called Initialization. I.e. your `Sample`-method is initializing the object, and must be called before the object can be used. I would try to avoid this, since it is easy to forget to call the initialization method. It is typically easier

Your last example would be of an optional property. I.e. A should work just fine if `objB` is not set by anyone, but may change its behavior if it is set.

To me this is a rater poor question. I do not think I have ever discussed composition vs aggregation, and composition vs inheritance is usually mentioned to advocate against inheritance. I suspect the real point is regarding lifetimes and disposal. Any disposable object needs to be disposed, and it should always be clear who is responsible for disposing the object. A somewhat common pattern is something like this:

```
public class MyClass : IDisposable{
    public MyDependency dep;
    public suppressDispose;
    public MyClass(MyDependency dep, bool suppressDispose = false) => (dep, suppressDispose ) = (dep, suppressDispose );
    public void Dispose(){
        if(!suppressDispose) dep.Dispose();
    }
}
```

That takes over ownership by default, but allow for an opt out if the dependency need to be used later.